# Routing not working in reactjs application

Tags: react-router, reactjs

I have created a reactjs app having three pages (components), App, Login and Register, where I need to navigate from page to page by entering the url in the browser but the navigation is not working for me. Entering any url just shows me the 'App' page.

following is the code that I have written in main.js file of the app and the url that I am using to navigate looks something like this `http://localhost:8080/#/login` or `http://localhost:8080/#/reg`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, NavLink, Redirect, Switch, hashHistory} from 'react-router-dom'
import App from './../jsx/App.jsx';
import Login from './../jsx/Login.jsx';
import Register from './../jsx/Register.jsx';

ReactDOM.render((
     <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <div>
            <Route path="/" component={App}/>
            <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
            <Route path="/reg" component={Register}/>
        </div>
    </Router>

), document.getElementById('app'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the route to match the root path exactly. Try this...

```
<Route exact path="/" component={App}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove **/** from your path in Route path in

```
<Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
            <Route path="/reg" component={Register}/>
```

try this it's working for me

entry class

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Layout from './Component/Layout.jsx';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory } from "react-router";

import Archives from './Component/Archives.jsx';
import Settings from './Component/Settings.jsx';

import Featured from './Component/Featured.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(
<Router history={hashHistory}>
<Route path="/" component={Layout}> 
//<IndexRoute component={Featured}></IndexRoute>
<Route path="archives" name="archives" component={Archives}></Route>
<Route path="settings" component={Settings}></Route>
<Route path="featured" component={Featured}></Route>
</Route>
</Router>,
document.getElementById('app'));

Layout class
{
render{

return(
<div>
      {this.props.children}
      <ul>
       <li><Link to="archives">archives</Link></li>
         <li><Link to="settings">settings</Link></li>
         <li><Link to="featured">featured</Link></li>
         </ul>

</div>

);
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react router 4, then that looks fine. However, you can try using a  as shown below:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" component={Home} />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

This is in latest versions of react. The Home component is as below:

```
 render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>Header Section</p>
            <Header/>
            <p>Home component</p>
            <Link to="/search">search</Link>
            <Route path="/search" component={Search}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

So most probably what you need to do is to just add a switch. Other solutions may be possible too. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Use BrowserRouter and Switch from 'react-router-dom'
if you use BrowserRouter no need to pass history as props as it handles itself.

Try this.

```
<Router>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={App}/>
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>
            <Route exact path="/reg" component={Register}/>
        </Switch>
</Router>
```